# How to take backup of Jenkins jobs to remote machine

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I want to take scheduled backup of Jenkins jobs form Jenkins server to some remote machine. I tried exploring several Jenkins plugins for that but none of that are not able to take backup to the remote machine.

I successfully take backup of the Jenkins workspace using the shell script but in that case it's hard to restore the backup.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If I can suggest a different approach - if you're using any kind of source control it'll be better to backup your files and configuration there. for example - if you will work with git you can open a repository for your Jenkins configuration.

Back up your:

- jobs folder
- nodes folder
- parent folder files (config.xml, all plugins configurations, etc.)

then it is only a matter of running a scheduled job from Jenkins every 12 hours running:

```
cd $JENKINS_HOME
git add --all
git commit -m "Automated backup commit: $BUILD_TIMESTAMP"
git push
```

* Make sure you have the right permissions to run those command on the master

This will enable you to:

- Keep backups for you Jenkins configuration
- Manage versions of backups
- View history of changes you made to your configurations

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice - although I don't see why you need to run the git commands with sudo.

Comment: @gareth_bowles I must admit it has to do with security policies with the company I work and the OS templates they offer. Your point is absolutely right and I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Dvir669 : thanks for sharing your thoughts, but we have lot of different projects using same Jenkins. Don't you think it will create the security threat to keep them in one central repository.

Comment: Use the same permissions you use to the backup location you're currently using. the Jenkins Admin should decide who gets authorized to view\modify that repository, and in general it shouldn't be published anywhere, as it is strictly a dev-ops repository - no one should have access to it otherwise.