# Migrating Jenkins server using Git?

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm using the SCM Sync configuration plugin for Jenkins with Git and wanted to know if there was a way to migrate the config/jobs from one Jenkins server to another one using Git. Specifically, can I sync the Jenkins in the original server to Git and then sync that same Git repository to a new Jenkins server?

I haven't found anything that indicates whether this is possible or how to do it.

Comment: You better do with rsync or similar and copy the whole jenkins home folder. Be aware to do it when the slave jenkins is offline.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317008/how-to-take-backup-of-jenkins-jobs-to-remote-machine/37320924#37320924  -> Maybe try that one, and on the second server use fetch rebase?